# Replacing an Exclamation mark at the end of a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I am writing a program that counts song lyrics. Right now I have it programmed to delete certain characters using line.replace, for example:

```
String computerComma=",";

String computerPeriod=".";

String nothing="";

line=line.replace(computerComma,nothing);

line=line.replace(computerPeriod,nothing);
```

and this works totally fine. However, when I try

```
String computerExclamation="!";

line=line.replace(computerExclamation,nothing);
```

it messes up my entire program and many of my word counters. Does anybody know the reason behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: The code snippet you showed should work just fine. `System.out.println("ab!bc".replace("!", ""));` for example. The error seems to lie somewhere else. So it would be nicer if you could show more code and what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

No. Works fine.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         String computerExclamation="!";
         String line = "i am a String !!.";
         line=line.replace(computerExclamation,"");
         System.out.println(line);  //i am a String .

    }
```

Error lies some where else.

You can see [here](https://ideone.com/PXqLx1).

Comment: Wrong. `replace()` doesn't take. `replaceAll()` takes a regex. Proof, this code `System.out.println("ab!bc".replace("!", ""));` works just fine, replacing the exclamation mark.

Comment: @R.J Sorry. My bad. Thought it's replaceall

Comment: And now its seems to be just a comment, than an actual answer.

Comment: Since that is a wrong assumption, replace is not working on !, I guess it would be an answer.

Comment: This was [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118993/216721) and that's why I commented that this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Not a correct answer!